# How to make manual corrections to Google Translated Content?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-translate

The following Google Webmaster Central Blog entry suggests that you can manually correct translations by Google translate for your own website, which go live immediately and are also shown to your visitors: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2012/05/now-you-can-polish-up-googles.html

Unfortunately this feature seems to be not online anymore. Does anyone know a similar solution to achieve these results?

We want to translate a WordPress WooCommerce website with a lot of products from English to Chinese and therefore have to decide if we want to translate everything manually or use automatic translation via Google translate. Since the automatic Google translation is much quicker we prefer that way but we want to correct the many incorrect translated terms.
In case there is no way to make manual corrections to the Google Translations we also thought about downloading the translated version and re-importing it into WooCommerce again to make the edits there.

Answer (score 0):

The feature looks like it's available at http://translate.google.com/manager/website/

Comment: Yes, we tried that but the code does not contain any elements that link it to a specific domain or user account so I'm not sure how the custom edits are saved/served by Google. It just looks like this: <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>